# Are paths with same image homotopic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This seems quite easy but I don't have any idea on how to prove it.

Say we have two paths $a,b$ on topological space $X$, and $a,b$ have same image, i.e. $a(I)=b(I),I=[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then is it true that $a$ and $b$ are homotopical?

If $X$ is simply connected this is definitely true but for more general cases I have no idea.

BTW, I'm wondering if every image of a path is simply connected (under their subspace topologies induced from $X$)? I haven't come up with a counterexample yet.

Comment: As the two answers below indicate, it depend on whether you are fixing the endpoints or not. I am guessing not, because you haven't specified that the two paths have the same endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any two paths $a, b : [0, 1] \to X$ with the same image in a topological space $X$ are always homotopic.

Proof:

Let $s, t \in[0, 1]$ such that $a(s) = b(t)$, always possible since $a, b$ have the same image. Now it is easy to show there is a homotopy between $a$ and the constant map to $a(s)$; likewise there is a homotopy between $b$ and the constant map to $b(t)$.▪️

What is *not* true is that any two paths with the same image are *homotopic rel endpoints*.

(Meaning: The endpoints are kept fixed throughout the homotopy. Which makes sense only when $a(0) = b(0)$ and $a(1) = b(1)$.)

Comment: As a user for $10$ years, I'm surprised you're not using MathJax

Comment: If I understand correctly, your proof in fact shows that we only require $a(I)\cap b(I)$ to be nonempty i.e. their images are not disjoint

Comment: Really all that is needed is that $X$ is path connected.

Comment: Cheerful Parsnip: Given that a and b have the same images, it doesn't matter whether X is path connected.

Comment: FShrike: Yes, it suffices for a(I) and b(I) to intersect nonemptily.

Comment: @DanAsimov indeed, I did not make my point clearly.

Answer (score 5):

No (assuming the endpoints have to be kept fixed). Take two loops in $S^1$ where one winds around it once and the other winds around it twice. Their image is clearly the same, but they are not homotopic (otherwise the fundamental group of $S^1$ would be trivial).